# Does a transaction cover the subroutines?

Tags: sql-server, transaction, rollback

When I `begin transaction` and `exec` a stored procedure, does that transaction cover the changes made by the stored procedure I executed? Would a `rollback transaction` cancel the changes made by the stored procedure which is executed?

Comment: You've tagged both SQL server and mysql. Which are you using?

Comment: @Phil ms sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the `rollback transaction` would rollback all changes made inside the stored procedure except if the stored procedure was itself to issue an unbalanced `COMMIT` which would raise an error

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
>   BEGIN and COMMIT statements.

but still lead to the transaction being committed. Both cases shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE T(proc_name sysname)

GO

CREATE PROC proc_1
AS
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('proc_1')

GO

CREATE PROC proc_2
AS
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('proc_2')
COMMIT;

GO

BEGIN TRAN
EXEC proc_1 
ROLLBACK
/*Table is empty. Transaction rolled back*/
SELECT * FROM T

GO

BEGIN TRAN
EXEC proc_2 
ROLLBACK
/*Table is not empty. Transaction was committed*/
SELECT * FROM T
```